# Transform from quadrilateral to quadrilateral with AffineTransform?

Tags: java, graphics, affinetransform, perspectivecamera

Is Java's `AffineTransform` insufficient to hold transformation from one convex quadrilateral to another?

Is this true, that transformation between convex quadrilaterals is fully covered by perspective transform?

Perspective matrix has 8 elements, while Java's has 6. Does this mean that here are insufficient coefficients?

This means that I can't code GUI where user would drag quadrilateral corners and get quadrilateral content transformed correspondently?

How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)  maintains parallel lines as parallel. A perspective transform is by definition does not, and therefore is not affine.

A [perspective transfrom](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.html) is included with the JAI ("Java Advanced Imaging") API but I'm not sure what's the official source for it after Oracle bought Sun.